# Why is my compiler telling me there is a Uncompilable source code?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I have trouble with NetBeans quite frequently. Earlier I was able to run this program no problem, but now, it tells me this after running it

"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code -cannot find symbol
symbol:   class Loop1
location: class hw7
    at hw7.main(hw7.java:72)"

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class forLoops {
void forLoop1(){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int cnt = 2;

    System.out.print("Enter n:");
    int n = in.nextInt();

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++){
            if (i == 1)
                System.out.print(1);
            else if (i > 1) {
                System.out.printf("%3d", cnt);
                cnt++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    }


void forLoop2(){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter n:");
    int n = in.nextInt();

    for (int i = 1; i < n+1; i++) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++){
           System.out.printf("%3d", i+sum);
           sum = sum + n-(j+1);
        }
        System.out.println();
        }
    }

void forLoop3(){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter n:");
    int n = in.nextInt();

    int x = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i < n+1; i++) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++){
           System.out.printf("%3d", i+sum);
           sum = sum + n-(j+1);
        }
        System.out.println();
        }
    }
}  
public class hw7 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    forLoops myL1 = new forLoops();
    myL1.forLoop1();
    forLoops myL2 = new forLoops();
    myL2.forLoop2();
    Loops myL3 = new forLoops();
    myL3.forLoop3();
}
```

}

Comment: Where are `Loop1`, `Loop2`, and `Loop3` defined?

Comment: Nowhere. He needs to instantiate the `forLoops` class.

Comment: Right.  The compiler cannot find Loop1 because it's not there.

Answer (score 2):

You're not instantiating the class correctly. Since it's name is `forLoops`, you need to do something like:

```
forLoops myL1 = new forLoops();
myL1.forLoop1();
forLoops myL2 = new forLoops();
myL2.forLoop2();
forLoops myL3 = new forLoops();
myL3.forLoop3();
```

*Unrelated to the question*, note that classes in Java **start with a capital letter**, by convention.

Comment: Downvoter, **do you mind** explaining your action ?

Answer (score 2):

This is line 72: `Loop1 myL1 = new Loop1();`

You are using a class named Loop1, but you have not defined it.